# Plastic paint on laptop

Tags: drawing, paint, plastic

I have this black touchpad with a red paint around it, how can I make this black? Does some vinyl exist? Paint? I tried to find some touchpad skins that matched the rest of the laptop, but i couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use acrylic paint or a carbon fiber vinyl. Not sure on how well the acrylic paint would work, but both myself and my fiance has used the carbon fiber

Comment: Thank you, I lean more towards vinyl as it is easy to apply and remove :)